# Unable to load the CSS and script files in JSP

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp

I am using  Spring MVC, and cannot load my CSS or script files.

My JSP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page session="false" language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<link
    href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/css/animate.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<script
    src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/wow.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Take a look at the html source code of the generated jsp website and see what the result of these expressions are. Then try them out in the browser.

Comment: Could you post the resource-handler config as well as the path to the css/js resources in your web-project?